# Tracking email read when sender opens the email

Tags: email, tracking

I have implemented email tracking feature.

When the receiver opens the email, the read count is increased.

But when the sender opens the email, it also increases the read counter.

Is there any way in which the read counter does not increase when the sender reads the email?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should explain your solution a bit. Like why sender and receiver have the same email. Do you use some API to send emails?

Comment: Hi Piro, sender and receiver don't have the same email address. The scenario is person A has sent an email to person B with a transparent pixel image embedded in the email body. When the person B reads the email, the read count increases which is good. But when the person A reads the same email, then also read count increases. I don't want the read count to increase when person A reads the same email.

Answer (score 1):

In my `background.js`, I used `chrome.webRequest` API to block the webrequest which renders the pixel image for the sender.

This way when the extension is installed for the sender, then the pixel image request will be blocked when the sender will read own email.

Here is the reference code from [chrome.webrequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)-

```
//block all the requests to www.evil.com
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```